# Laravel Passport use Different Model

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

I want to add a custom guard to Laravel that uses Passport but with different model (not User), but when I try to set the user for this guard  it is not working.

config/auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'conference' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'participants',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'participants' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Participant::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'spark::auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],

];
```

in the controller I am setting the user for the custom guard:

```
    auth()->guard('conference')->setUser($participant);
```

api.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{activity}', 'middleware' => ['auth:conference', 'api']], function () { //

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'participant/{participant}'], function () {
        Route::any('join', 'API\ConferenceController@join');

    });
});
```

Participant model:

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Participant extends Authenticatable
{
    use Enums, SoftDeletes, RequiresUUID, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
```

but I can't access the route I get 401. When I change the provider for the 'conference' guard to be 'users' it works without problem.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

This might help:

My AdminAPI Url: https://example.com/api/login
My Customer API Url: https://example.com/api.customer/login

adding this to any ServiceProvider (I have added in RouteServiceProvider.php before custom route)

```
// Fix/Support for multiple user with different table by changing provider on api.customer circumstances
  Config::set('auth.guards.api.provider', request()->input('provider', starts_with(request()->path(), 'api.customer') ? 'customers' : 'users'));`
```

and must add your custom provider in providers array in config/auth.php

```
'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Customer::class,
    ],
```

Comment: any update on this issue? looking for another work-around without being vendor or config::set related

Answer (score -4):

If you just only change User model to 'participants' you can replace provider to 'participants' in api. Multi auth I found a temporary solution, idea comes from https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161

and http://esbenp.github.io/2017/03/19/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-4/

1. Laravel\Passport\Brigde\UserRepository.php file add:

```js
public function getEntityByUserCredentials($username, $password, $grantType, ClientEntityInterface $clientEntity, $provider) {
  $provider = config('auth.guards.' . $provider . '.provider');
  if (is_null($model = config('auth.providers.' . $provider . '.model'))) {
   throw new RuntimeException('Unable to determine authentication model from configuration.');
  }
  if (method_exists($model, 'findForPassport')) {
   $user = (new $model)->findForPassport($username);
  } else {
   $user = (new $model)->where('email', $username)->first();
  }
  if (!$user) {
   return;
  } elseif (method_exists($user, 'validateForPassportPasswordGrant')) {
   if (!$user->validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)) {
    return;
   }
  } elseif (!$this->hasher->check($password, $user->getAuthPassword())) {
   return;
  }
  return new User($user->getAuthIdentifier());
 }
```

2. League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant.php 78 line add

   $provider = $this->getRequestParameter('provider', $request);

and 94 line add $provider, like:

```
$user = $this->userRepository->getEntityByUserCredentials(
        $username,
        $password,
        $this->getIdentifier(),
        $client,
        $provider
    );
```

3. Write LoginProxy(in fact it should be receive different Model in constructor ) like:

```js
class LoginProxy {
 const REFRESH_TOKEN = 'refreshToken';
 private $client;
 private $user;
 public function __construct(User $user, Client $client) {
  $this->user = $user;
  $this->client = $client;
 }
 public function attemptLogin($mobile, $password) {
  $user = $this->user->where('mobile', $mobile)->first();
  if (!is_null($user)) {
   return $this->proxy('password', [
    'username' => $mobile,
    'password' => $password,
   ]);
  }
  return response()->json('error for 401', 401);
 }
 public function attemptRefresh() {
  $refreshToken = $this->request->cookie(self::REFRESH_TOKEN);
  return $this->proxy('refresh_token', [
   'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
  ]);
 }
 public function proxy($grant_type, array $data = []) {
  $data = array_merge($data, [
   'client_id' => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID'),
   'client_secret' => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_SECRET'),
   'grant_type' => $grant_type,
   'scope' => '*',
  ]);
  $response = $this->client->post(url('/oauth/token'), [
   'form_params' => $data,
  ]);
  $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
  return response()->json([
   'token_type' => $data->token_type,
   'access_token' => $data->access_token,
   'refresh_token' => $data->refresh_token,
   'expires_in' => $data->expires_in,
  ], 200);
 }
 public function logout() {
  $accessToken = $this->auth->user()->token();
  $refreshToken = $this->db
   ->table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
   ->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)
   ->update([
    'revoked' => true,
   ]);
  $accessToken->revoke();
 }
}
```

4. in your LoginController, call certain method:

```js
class LoginController extends Controller {
 private $loginProxy;
 public function __construct(LoginProxy $loginProxy) {
  $this->loginProxy = $loginProxy;
 }
 public function login(LoginRequest $request) {
  $mobile = $request->get('mobile');
  $password = $request->get('password');
  $provider = $request->get('provider');
  return $this->loginProxy->attemptLogin($mobile, $password, $provider);
 }
 public function refresh(Request $request) {
  return $this->response($this->loginProxy->attemptRefresh());
 }
 public function logout() {
  $this->loginProxy->logout();
  return $this->response(null, 204);
 }
```

Now you can post different provider params to it.

Comment: @howong-alex is it really ok to change the vendor code?! What will happen when you want to update the repository?

Comment: It's not okay to modify vendor code. If you do, your changes will be overwritten by composer updates.

Comment: Mega dumb answer. It's basic knowledge to never and never modify files in the vendor directory.